# Body response empty after first call in Mockito

Tags: java, mockito, okhttp

I use `Mockito` to mock a `OkHttp` class in my application. The first time the mock works good and I get `"foo"` as response in body, but the second time is empty. I tried to debug it and looks like the mock is working, I don't know why it doesn't for the second call.

**My test:**

```
@Test
void get500() throws IOException {
    String responseMessage = "foo";
    int responseCode = 500;

    final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = mock(OkHttpClient.class);
    final Call remoteCall = mock(Call.class);
    final Response responseBuilder = new Response.Builder()
            .request(new Request.Builder().url(url).build())
            .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_1_1)
            .code(responseCode).message("").body(
                    ResponseBody.create(
                            responseMessage,
                            MediaType.parse("application/json")
                    ))
            .build();

    when(remoteCall.execute()).thenReturn(responseBuilder);
    when(okHttpClient.newCall(any())).thenReturn(remoteCall);
    
    MyHttp myHttp = new MyHttp(okHttpClient);
    ResponseServer response = myHttp.get("http://url.com");
    Assertions.assertEquals(response.getBody(), responseMessage);
}
```

And this is `MyHttp` class:

```
public class MyHttp {
    protected final OkHttpClient client;
    
    public MyHttp(OkHttpClient client) {
        this.client = client;
    }
    
    public ResponseServer get(String url) throws IOException {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .get()
                .build();
        
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        String responseBody = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).string();
        Assertions.assertEquals(response.getBody(), "foo");

        Response response2 = client.newCall(request).execute();
        String responseBody2 = Objects.requireNonNull(response2.body()).string();
        Assertions.assertEquals(response2.getBody(), "foo");  // response is empty
    }
}
```

**Edited:**

Mocked Response as bellow but didn't work:

```
Response mockResponse = mock(Response.class);
when(mockResponse.request()).thenReturn(new Request.Builder().url(url).build());
when(mockResponse.protocol()).thenReturn(Protocol.HTTP_1_1);
when(mockResponse.code()).thenReturn(responseCode);
when(mockResponse.message()).thenReturn("");
when(mockResponse.body()).thenReturn(
        ResponseBody.create(
                responseMessage,
                MediaType.parse("application/json")
        ));
```

Comment: Possibly from reusing `responseBuilder` - body content can usually only be read once.

Comment: Mock Response too instead of returning real one in your test. it could solve the problem described  by @Andrew S.

Comment: @VladUlshin, I edited my solution to add the mocked response. Still didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced your example with some correction (your snippets has compilation errors)

My partial maven pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
      <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
      <version>4.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

MyHttp class:

```
public class MyHttp {
  protected final OkHttpClient client;

  public MyHttp(OkHttpClient client) {
    this.client = client;
  }

  public Response get(String url) throws IOException {
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .get()
        .build();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    String responseBody = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).string();
    Assert.isTrue("foo".equals(responseBody));
    //Assertions.assertEquals(response.getBody(), "foo");

    Response response2 = client.newCall(request).execute();
    String responseBody2 = Objects.requireNonNull(response2.body()).string();
    //Assertions.assertEquals(response2.getBody(), "foo");  // response is empty
    Assert.isTrue("foo".equals(responseBody2));
    return response2;
  }
}
```

Test class

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class MyHttpTest {

  @Test
  void get500() throws IOException {
    String responseMessage = "foo";
    int responseCode = 500;

    final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = mock(OkHttpClient.class);
    final Call remoteCall = mock(Call.class);
/*    final Response response = new Response.Builder()
        .request(new Request.Builder().url("http://url.com").build())
        .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_1_1)
        .code(responseCode).message("").body(
            ResponseBody.create(
                responseMessage,
                MediaType.parse("application/json")
            ))
        .build();*/

    Response mockResponse = mock(Response.class);
    ResponseBody mockResponseBody = mock(ResponseBody.class);

    when(mockResponseBody.string()).thenReturn("foo");
    when(mockResponse.body()).thenReturn(mockResponseBody);

    when(remoteCall.execute()).thenReturn(mockResponse);
    when(okHttpClient.newCall(any())).thenReturn(remoteCall);

    MyHttp myHttp = new MyHttp(okHttpClient);
    Response response = myHttp.get("http://url.com");
    Assertions.assertEquals(response.body().string(), responseMessage);
  }
}
```